# Date variables in copyright templates

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij documentation [says](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/copyright-profiles.html):

```
DateInfo has the following properties:
  year      int     The current year.
  month     int     The current month (1-12).
```

I can't make Intellij generate current year for me. I tried all possible: `$DateInfo.year`, `${DateInfo.getYear()}`, etc.

Comment: DataInfo or DateInfo ?

Comment: After your edit yes :)

Comment: any constructive comments?

Comment: Sorry, computer says no

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documentation says:

> $today    DateInfo    The current date and time.
>
> ...
>
> DateInfo has the following properties:
>
> year  int The current year.
>
> month int The current month (1-12).

Try: `$today.year`

As this is Velocity template (?) you don't have to use braces - { }

Cheers

Comment: Any problems? Try $today.year

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your answer first. Can you edit your answer and put `$today.year` into it?